# Access a parent component's method onClick in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

So as the title suggests I'm just trying to access a parent component's method in React via a child component. I understand this can be accomplished via props, however I'm attempting to do it via an onClick event and it doesn't seem to like that. Here is a basic example of my problem.

```
var Child = React.createClass({

render: function() {
    return (

        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click Here</button>
  );
 }
});   


var Parent = React.createClass({

onClick: function() {
    console.log('I've been clicked');
  },


render: function() {
    return (

        <Child />

  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('Parent'));
```

How do I get the Child component's button onClick event to fire the Parent component's onClick method? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass Parent's onClick function to Child as a prop:

```
<Child myClick={this.onClick} />
```

and then use it in Child:

```
<button onClick={this.props.myClick}>Click Here</button>
```

Entire code:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<button onClick={this.props.myClick}>Click Here</button>)
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    onClick: function() {
        console.log("I've been clicked");
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<Child myClick={this.onClick} />);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a perfect answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just the way React is, you can pass it down a reference to the callback function to the child as a prop and then have the child call the function using the prop. This is the React way and cannot be done outside of props when it comes to a child accessing a parent property.

if you want to do something more in the child component you can define an onclick function inside of your child component and have it do anything additional or add arguments to the `this.props.onClick`.